# How to Change height,width in curlView?

Tags: android

I follow this link https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl now I want to modify size of the curlview,I already try to change android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" in main.xml file but it is not working.
So, Please tell me How to change curlView height,width and background.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For width and height change, you could put that custom view in a Linear Layout and change Linear Layout properties like below.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.mobinius.hungama.curl.CurlView
            android:id="@+id/curl"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

For background color

```
mCurlView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF202830);
```